# Copy -partial-datename- file from dir to another dir

Tags: python

everyday I need to copy file from dir to another dir; this file is created everyday and today will be:
"20220718T17_versionName=1.3.2.5.tar.gz"
Tomorrow will be:"20220719T17_versionName=1.3.2.5.tar.gz"...and so on.

I need to copy it from his folder to another folder and was thinking to select it by date, something like: go to folder-->search file that contain today date in first 8 characters in filename-->copy to the other dir...

I ve tried with this code

```
import os    
import shutil
import datetime

date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")

fromfolder = r'C:\path1\...'
tofolder = r'C:\path2\...'  
ext = (gz)  


if filename.startswith(f"{date}.format(ext)"):
 shutil.copy(os.path.join(folders, filename), tofolder)
```

obviously doesn't works! :D

How can I select this daily created file and copy it to the destination dir?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope following code will help you.

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime

date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")

fromfolder = r'C:\path1\...'
tofolder = r'C:\path2\...'


for filename in os.listdir(fromfolder):
    if filename.startswith("{}".format(date)):
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(fromfolder, filename), tofolder)
        print('move finished of {}'.format(filename))
```